# Exploding or Splitting Value in DB Query (PHP/MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql

One field in my database table (symbols) displays URL's that look like these:

```
arizona/flag
arizona/flower
arizona/flower2
arizona/bird
```

Another database table (articles) features content, like this:

```
+----------+-----------------+-------------+
| State-ID | PostURL         |     Article |
+----------+-----------------+-------------+
| us-az    | flag            | (text)      |
| us-az    | flower          | (text)      |
| us-az    | flower2         | (text)      |
| us-az    | bird            | (text)      |
| us-fl    | flag            | (text)      |
+----------+-----------------+-------------+
```

So my database query has to join these two tables. I simply added a new field to the first table (symbols), PostURL, with values like flag, flower, flower2, etc.

It works, but it's a little redundant, and I'd like to streamline my table. So I realized I could simply join the tables on the second segment of each value in Symbols.URL.

My current join clause looks something like this:

```
LEFT JOIN articles ART ON ART.ID = Sym.IDArea AND ART.PostURL = Sym.DesigGen
```

I want to change it to this:

```
LEFT JOIN gs_articles_world_usa ART ON ART.ID = GS.IDArea AND ART.PostURL = [2nd segment in value from field Sym.URL]
```

So the values for that second segment for the URL's florida/flower and florida/flower2 would  be **flower** and **flower2**.

I know how to use Explode to isolate these values AFTER I've extracted the values in a query. But is there a way to isolate those values in the initial query? In other words, can I use Explode or some other function inside the query itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [LOCATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_locate) to find the position of the slash and use [SUBSTR](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substr) to clip the string after the position of the slash.

```
SUBSTR(Sym.URL, LOCATE('/', Sym.URL) + 1)
```

Take note that `LOCATE` will get the position of the first occurrence of the string you are looking for. The code above works only if you will always have 1 slash in `Sym.URL`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no native way to do this in MySQL, but apparently [as this blog describes](http://blog.fedecarg.com/2009/02/22/mysql-split-string-function/) you can create your own `SPLIT_STR` function.

First the DB user must have `INSERT` rights to create the function.  Next, create the function by running this as a query:

```
CREATE FUNCTION SPLIT_STR(
  x VARCHAR(255),
  delim VARCHAR(12),
  pos INT
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
RETURN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos),
       LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos -1)) + 1),
       delim, '');
```

Once that is done you can access & use the function using this syntax:

```
SELECT SPLIT_STR(string, delimiter, position);
```

So using your example—and without seeing the larger MySQL query—perhaps something like this would work:

```
SELECT SPLIT_STR(Sym.URL, '/', 2) as Split_Sym_URL from [table name];
```

My naming of `Split_Sym_URL` is just my choice. Feel free to change that to whatever else works for you. And `[table name]` should be whatever your table name is.

Then you can use that `Split_Sym_URL` in your `JOIN` like this:

```
LEFT JOIN gs_articles_world_usa ART ON ART.ID = GS.IDArea AND ART.PostURL = Split_Sym_URL
```